# How do I select random rows (say 10 from 100) from mysql database and display them with a number in series

Tags: php, mysql

How do I select random rows (say 10 from 100) from mysql database and display them with a number in series

Any random rows get selected and give them like

```
1. XXXXX
2. YYYYY
3. ZZZZZ
```

but in database they are not in series

Comment: What is your mysql version ? Also, think `order by rand()`

Comment: Maybe this answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast

Comment: Let's pretend instead that you want to select 3 random rows from 10. With that in mind, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: For an ordered list you can use HTML `<ol></ol>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PHP `rand()` function. Here's the tutorial for it : https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_rand.asp
Also to gave them an ordered list, use `<ol>`.

Example

```
$iWantThisManyRow = 4;
$minNumber = 10;
$maxNumber = 100;

for ($i=0; $i < $iWantThisManyRow; $i++) { 
    $rand = rand($minNumber, $maxNumber);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tables` WHERE `id` = '$rand'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $data = $data['field'];
        echo "<ol>$data</ol";
    }else{
        // Whatever you wanted to do when nothing was founded.
    }
}
```

Please note that you might want to use prepared statement and the example above is assuming `$link` is the database connection and `field` is the column name.