# I want to Select random rows from database and list them out in order. Below is the code

Tags: php, mysql

This is the Code:

```
<?php
    $db=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
    $sql = 'SELECT `Questions`, `OptionA`, `OptionB`, `OptionC`, `OptionD` FROM `ccoai questions` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2';
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    echo '<table width="100%">
    ';

    // Print each file
    for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++)
    {
    echo "<ol><li>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       // $nice_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime( $row['doregistration'] ));
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>{$row['Questions']}</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type='radio' value='{$row['OptionA']}'>{$row['OptionA']}</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type='radio' value='{$row['OptionB']}'>{$row['OptionB']}</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type='radio' value='{$row['OptionC']}'>{$row['OptionC']}</td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type='radio' value='{$row['OptionD']}'>{$row['OptionD']}</td></tr>
            </tr>";
    }

    // Close table
    echo '</li></ol></table>';
    }
}

// Free the result
$result->free();
}
 else
{
echo 'Error! SQL query failed:';
echo "<pre>{$db->error}</pre>";
}

// Close the mysql connection
$db->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. What's the problem?

Comment: Right ^ and didn't you already ask something similar already and got an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52644562/1415724

Comment: it doesnt work. It is stuck at 1. doesnt go beyond 1 in numbering

Comment: Yes I did ask but others doesnt seem to know to actual problem

Comment: What is stuck at 1 ? In  your code, I dont see anything printing numbering.

Comment: echo "<ol><li>";

Comment: I am trying to list them with <ol>

Comment: Get rid of your `for` statement. It is trying to go up to `$limit` which you have not set.

Comment: Yes. for is a mistake. I removed for loop. Still the problem persist.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work. I'm fairly sure you can't have list tags in the middle of a table tag that like, and you're iterating through all of the results before you hit the next list element anyway. Use a counter instead.

Comment: Update your code in your question to the latest version. Also, you have a `LIMIT` in your query set to 2. How many rows are you expecting?

Comment: I just want every row with a number in order may be 1. 2. 3. or i. ii. iii.

Comment: Remove the for loop and the list tags. Add a counter before the loop `$i = 1;`, echo it out before your question, then increment it at the end of the while loop.

Comment: The issue is that you are only outputting `<li>` once. You need to move `<li>` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: <td><ol><li>{$row['Questions']}</li></ol></td></tr>  I tried this and this also doesnt work

Comment: <ol> needs to be outside the loop, <li> inside

Comment: you are best of giving us an ideal of what you want the finished article to look like. Edit your question with a display of what you need it to look like

Answer (score 0):

Documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol

Open the `<ol>` once and then add a single `<li>` for each row.

**Edit** - removed `<tr>` content because I am not sure what the expected output should be.

```
<?php
...
// Open the <ol> (ordered-list) once and the add one <li> (list item) for each row.
echo '<table width="100%"><ol>';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Add a single <li> for each row.
    echo "<li>...</li>";
}

// Close the <ol> 
echo '</ol></table>';
...
```

Comment: `Its still not working.` doesn't help me help you. What are you seeing? What are you not seeing? Is it because you're `LIMIT`ing your query to 2 rows and you're expecting more rows?

Comment: you have <tr> tags inside of <tr> tags and are missing a <tr> tag at that. Im not sure syntax like that works